# How to filter by utm_id in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I wonder if there is a way to filter data by utm_id. I see i can filter by utm_source, utm_medium or utm_campaign but not for utm_id

If we can't filter by utm_id, what is the real use of this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select `Campaign code` as secondary dimension to see it in the report.